# While web scraping, when trying to count the amount of items on a page I get 1 even though there is more than 1

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to web scrape a page as practice. At one point I am trying to count the amount of HTML divs with a specific class name. Even though there are more than one when I inspect the page, when using the `len()` function it only counts one. The code is as follows

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'random_url'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"row"})

len(containers)
```

Finally the `len(containers)` is only returning one, when I can clearly see more than one in the browser.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do `print(page_soup)` to see if the div's are there. They may have been added by javascript.

Comment: if I make a mock html page with two `<div class="row">` elements. And use your code as is. I get a list of two elements. So urllib might not be loading all the elements you see in your browser. Try looking at what you're getting by passing `print(page_soup.prettify())` to a file.

Comment: To progress further we really would need to know the URL you are trying to scrape. Also show the information you are trying to extract.

Comment: `my_url = 'https://www.haart.co.uk/branch-finder'` I am trying to extract the address, email and phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address information is being created using javascript, as such you will not be able to read the information via the HTML without using something like selenium to automate a web browser.

In your case though, all of the address information is actually being returned as JSON to that page, so all you need to do is to recreate the call that the browser is making to get the data and use that instead:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import json
import re

my_url = 'https://www.haart.co.uk/umbraco/api/branches/getsales/HRT'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_json = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

addresses = json.loads(page_json)

for address in addresses:
    print(address['headline'])
    print(re.sub(r'\<.*?\>', '', address['address']))
    print(address['email'].strip())
    print(address['telephone'])
    print()
```

This would display the addresses starting as:

```
Abbots Langley Estate Agents
haart Abbots Langley,30 High Street,Abbots Langley,Hertfordshire,WD5 0AR.
abbots.langley@haart.co.uk
01923 269444

Arnold Estate Agents
Arnold haart,12 Croft Street,Arnold,Nottinghamshire,NG5 7DX.
arnold@haart.co.uk
0115 926 8877

Ashford (Kent) Estate Agents
haart Ashford (Kent),3-4 Kings Parade, High Street,Ashford, Kent, TN24 8TA.
ashfordkent@haart.co.uk
01233 620340
```

This uses a regular expression to remove the extra HTML formatting tags inside the address.

If you use your browser's network tools, you can see all the requests the page makes. In amongst all that you should be able to see the addresses as JSON. It then lets you see the request that was made to get that data.